# How to select all columns plus a custom one from table by using EF LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

How can I do this using LINQ in entity framework ?

```
SELECT TOP 1 
       'abc' as test
      ,T_Users.*
FROM T_Users
ORDER BY T_Users.BE_Name
```

I have this:

```
var initme = (
    from c in Repo.T_Users
    orderby c.BE_Name
    select new {
        test = "abc",
        c
    }
).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this gives:

```
object
{
   abc
  ,c
}
```

instead of

```
object
{
   abc
   ,c.col_1
   ,c.col_2
   ,c.col_3
   ...
   ,c.col_N
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible; I'm afraid you'll just have to use:

```
var initme = (from c in Repo.T_Users
                          orderby c.BE_Name

                          select new
            {
                 test =  "abc",
                 c1 = c.col_1, 
                 c2 = c.col_2,
                 ... 
            }
```

Comment: That sucks, I precisely hoped there was a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **manually specify all columns** in your `select` clause in LINQ, there is no shorter way.

```
var initme = (from c in Repo.T_Users
              orderby c.BE_Name
              select new
              {
                 test =  "abc",
                 col1 = c.col_1,
                 col12 = c.col_2
                 /....
              }
             ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify all the fields you need in the select. 
Or you can create a custom object like repoDto that has all properties the properties of repo table plus your test field that you're going to populate after the query.